# odbc_fetch_row - while() doesn't keep variable after 2nd loop

Tags: php, while-loop

During my while loop, the first var_dump works correctly. The 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and 5th loop do NOT contain data for $MDBrecord.

Why doesn't $MDBrecord retain it's information after the first loop?

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM OrderDetails WHERE OrdersID=1023";
$details=odbc_exec($MDB,$sql);

var_dump($MDBrecord); // Works Great!

while (odbc_fetch_row($details)){

    var_dump($details); // WORKS every time, but...

    var_dump($MDBrecord); // DOESNT WORK after 1 of 5 loops

}
```

Comment: What is this variable `$MDBrecord`

Comment: If you want to fetch the data from ODBC, here's an example:
````$sql = "SELECT * FROM OrderDetails WHERE OrdersID=1023";
$result = odbc_exec($db, $sql);
while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
   echo odbc_result($result, 1), "\n"; //shows the first field
}
````
If that's not what you meant - you need to tell us what the $MDBrecord variable is.

Comment: @Jorge - it doesn't really matter. It contains a few things like prices, img thumbnail urls - and it works just fine. It doesn't work inside the loop.

Comment: @Paulina - Thanks, but the problem isn't retrieving data. It's using $MDBrecord while in the $details while loop.

Comment: is this the _whole_ code?

Comment: As @user623952 said - there needs to be some other part of the code that overwrites `$MDBrecord`. Is it returned from another odbc query? That may explain why it's removed after the next query is run.

Comment: @User - No, this is the snippet that is running in a test file. Same result in either location! I've been Googling, some other users are experiencing the same issue - no solutions...

Comment: okay, please include more. specifically anything inside of the loop. `$MDBrecord` is just a normally array or something?  nothing special?  are you modifying it at all anywhere in the loop?  doing a function that might manipulate it by reference..?

Comment: Can you try `print_r($MDBrecord);` inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Solved (sort of).

Earlier in this function, I was taking another ODBC object, and creating an actual object. Looks like you just can't do that in this nested loop situation.

Thanks for all those who helped!